# Doctrine MongoDB reference hydrate false and prime

Tags: php, mongodb, doctrine-orm, doctrine-odm, odm

Good evening everyone.

Please, help me with my Doctrine/Mongo problem.

I have a document, which has a ReferenceOne to another document and ReferenceMany to other document.

So I need to run one query to get full document tree for my first document as associative array.

I'm trying to do it like that:

```
return $this->createQueryBuilder()
        ->field('category')->references($category)
        ->field('vendor')->prime()
        ->field('chars')->prime()
        ->hydrate(false)
        ->getQuery()
        ->execute();
```

But as result i get array like this:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [_id] => MongoId Object
            (
                [$id] => 52e374c21c83735f098b4567
            )

        [category] => Array
            (
                [$ref] => Category
                [$id] => MongoId Object
                    (
                        [$id] => 52dc56eb1c837345098b4567
                    )

                [$db] => doctrine
            )

        [chars] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [$ref] => ProductChar
                        [$id] => MongoId Object
                            (
                                [$id] => 52e374c21c83735f098b4568
                            )

                        [$db] => doctrine
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [$ref] => ProductChar
                        [$id] => MongoId Object
                            (
                                [$id] => 52e374c21c83735f098b4569
                            )

                        [$db] => doctrine
                    )

            )

        [href] => href-test
        [price] => 500
        [title] => test
        [vendor] => Array
            (
                [$ref] => Vendor
                [$id] => MongoId Object
                    (
                        [$id] => 52e170571c837360098b4567
                    )

                [$db] => doctrine
            )

    )

)
```

But I need not just only IDs of referenced documents, but all values as well.

So now I don't know how to retrieve whole document array tree.

Thank you all in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Priming requires hydration. If you investigate [`Query::execute()`](https://github.com/doctrine/mongodb-odm/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/ODM/MongoDB/Query/Query.php#L218), you'll see that it abruptly returns if hydration is disabled. The primer handling would occur later on in that method if hydration was enabled. I've created [#800](https://github.com/doctrine/mongodb-odm/issues/800) to ensure we document this limitation, since it is not discussed in [Priming References](https://doctrine-mongodb-odm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/priming-references.html). It may be possible to implement support for priming in the future, but we don't have any present plans for it.